# Sales tax on Food

Tags: united-states, sales-tax, texas

I bought a prepared salad at Walmart today in Houston, Texas. I thought it a bit strange to pay tax on food, but I understand their reasoning. What was still confusing was that I was charged an 8.25% sales tax on that 2.98 salad.

If I understand correctly, Texas, when charging tax on food uses 6.25% and can go up to 8.05% on groceries. I have seen nothing quoting 8.25% sales tax on food in Texas, except my receipt from Walmart.

What is the sales tax on prepared food items in Texas?

Answer (score 11):

> The Texas state sales and use tax rate is 6.25 percent, but local
>   taxing jurisdictions (cities, counties, special-purpose districts and
>   transit authorities) also may impose sales and use tax up to 2 percent
>   for a total maximum combined rate of 8.25 percent.
>   -- https://comptroller.texas.gov/taxes/sales/faq/local.php

Comment: And here's the breakdown: 6.25% state, 1% city, %1 transportation: https://www.avalara.com/taxrates/en/state-rates/texas/cities/houston.html

Answer (score -2):

The reason your salad was taxable is that it was *prepared*.  In Texas (and probably most other places), prepared food is taxable.  If you buy the individual ingredients, it's not.

https://comptroller.texas.gov/taxes/publications/96-280.pdf

Comment: The op was not asking why it was taxed, but questioned the amount of sales tax.